# How can I fix the charset on my project?

Tags: java, html, forms, jpa, character-encoding

It is a JPA and
I`m getting the word "descriï¿½ï¿½o" on DB, and in my debug on serverside, right before the persistence, when it receives from the *Form* it is like "descri��o".

I have a form, `<form action="..." method="post">`, it has some fields and sends to a REST service, @post, and is in there that my breakpoint comes and show it.

I used `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />` on the head of the form HTML page, but it is still not as I want...

**Problem:** bad characters on server side.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For me the following works - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: Which database do you use ? It seems the problem is in database, data and registered encoding are not matching.

Comment: @nikhil Yes, i have already tried that, it is still the same problem.

Comment: Maybe it's not UTF-8 ?

Comment: It's what @Toilal says. You have a different encoding in your DB.

Comment: @Toilal But on my debug on server side, right after the form submit, and before it goes to DB, my debug variables show �, on Eclipse. But I`ll check the DB charset anyway, it is a SQL DB.

Comment: So it doesn't come from the DB you're right. I though you were reading from Database, but you are performing a POST to write in the DB actually.

Comment: Please add more information on how the "descriï¿½ï¿½o" string is build ... Does it comes from a FORM POST from the web application ?

Comment: What exactly is your application? Is it a Spring web app?

Comment: @Toilal - I added a second paragraph, sorry for that. The characters is on the Form to the service, and I don't know if is the form or the service that is wrong.

Comment: @Thiago - It is an app which uses JAX-RS and JPA, for CRUD operations and uses Liberty runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta tag is invalid ...

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

This should fix issue with the form.

You can also try the form [accept-charset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp) attribute.

Comment: I have already tried this, and it didn't work for me, the first tag, and with the 'accept-charset' attribute.

Comment: Did you really tried this ? or the one you have written in the question ? `content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"` => is not valid, you need to have a single `content` attribute with value `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. note the `;` character

Comment: It is now `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` and `<form action='...'  method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">`. I appreciate your help, and I hope i`m not bothering you Tolial